# Basic question concerning equivalence of categories

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $C,D$ are categories and $F:C \rightarrow D$ covariant functor which is an equivalence together with a functor $G:D  \rightarrow C$ . How can I then show that $ G \cdot F :Mor_{C}(X,Y) \rightarrow Mor_{C}( G \cdot F(X), G \cdot F(Y))$ is a bijection? I fail to see it is surjective.

Comment: What definition are you working from? An adjunction with unit and counit isomorphism? If so then there is a nice result which says that the right adjoint of an adjunction is full if and only if each component of the count is an epimorphism, and the right adjoint if faithful if and only if each component is a split monomorphism. (see Theorem 1 page 97 of Mac Lane's Categories for the working mathematician, second addition).

Answer (score 1):

This follows from a more general fact that both $F$ and $G$ are fully faithful.

There is a nice characterization: a functor $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ is an equivalence of categories if and only if it is 1) fully faithful (meaning that $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C} (X,Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{D} (F (X), F (Y))$ is a natural bijection) and 2) essentially surjective (meaning that for every object $A\in \mathcal{D}$ there exists $X\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $F (X) \cong A$).

It is an instuctive exercise to show that any equivalence is fully faithful. Note that you have families of natural isomorphisms $\eta_X\colon X\xrightarrow{\cong} G F (X)$, so by looking at the corresponding naturality squares it is easy to show that

1) $F$ is faithfull: $F (f) = F (f')$ implies $G F (f) = G F (f')$ and then $f = f'$.

2) $F$ is full: for an arrow $F(X) \xrightarrow{g} F(Y)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ you can find an arrow $f$ such that $G F (f) = G (g)$. This implies $F (f) = g$ by 1).

---

**Edit**: in your particular case, to see that $f \mapsto GF (f)$ is surjective, look at the naturality square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{\eta_X}>>  GF (X) \\
@VV f V        @VV GF (f) V\\
Y @>\eta_Y>> GF (Y)
\end{CD}$$

$\eta_X$ and $\eta_Y$ are isomorphisms, hence $GF (f) = \eta_Y\circ f\circ \eta_X^{-1}$. So for any given morphism $g\colon GF (X) \to GF (Y)$ you may consider $f = \eta_Y^{-1}\circ g\circ \eta_X$, and then $GF (f) = g$.

Comment: I assumed that your definition of an equivalence is having $F$ and $G$ such that $Id_\mathcal{C} \cong G\circ F$ and $F\circ G \cong Id_\mathcal{D}$ (that is, families of natural isomorphisms $\eta_X\colon X\xrightarrow{\cong} G F (X)$ and $\epsilon_Y\colon FG (Y) \xrightarrow{\cong} Y$).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for your answer!